# Super (Windows) key presses are not registered

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, keymap

I have a notebook computer with full sized keyboard, however, the super (windows) key is not producing any output, e.g. when I try to bind it to some action, the mapping program is not seeing the keypresses. I've tried to check it with `xev` under Linux, but it's not registering button presses either.

I can remember that at some point in time I've used some tool under Windows to disable the key, but I can't remember it's name. Is there a way to enable this button back? What mechanism could have been used to disable the button in the first place?

Comment: Unlikely that any software could block the key for both Windows and Linux. Try to clean under the key, if possible for this notebook.

Comment: I agree that this seems pretty unlikely, but it's the fact. By the way it's a new notebook and I have decent cleaning habits :)

Comment: If it's new, you could use the warranty.

Comment: What is the output of `grep Super .config/xmodmaprc`? It will tell if your Super key is bound to any keycode defined by xorg.

Comment: @kait there is no such file on my system. Could you clarify the path please?